# Iterate Contact IDs from Users Data base to get contact data

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs-observables

i do not really understand map operators, have seen videos and tutorials for hours in angular and trying to get this solved.

I use a firestore database with users. Every user has an array with the ID's from other users.
I want to get the user Data for each ID. Every UserData for each ID should be pushed in a contacts-Array.
The last thing I tried was a contactData$ Observable to create an Observable from the current user Data.

getFbContactData : loaded in constructor, gets the IDs from current users with all the observables and transforms the data into contact-Objects:

```
  getFbContactData() {
    this.contacts = [];
    this.activeUsersDoc.get().pipe(switchMap(userSnapshot => {

        return from<string[]>(userSnapshot.data()['contacts']);
    })).pipe(concatMap((contactId) => {
           this.contactUsersDoc = this.usersCollection.doc(contactId);
           this.getContactData(contactId);
      return this.contactData$
    })).pipe(switchMap(() => this.contactData$)
    ).subscribe((contact) => {
    })
  }
```

getContactData - to get all the userData for the currently processed ID from the activeUsers UserId and transform into contactObjects for returning it to upper main Observable somehow.

```
  getContactData(userId) {
    const contactUserDoc = this.usersCollection.doc(userId);
    contactUserDoc.get().pipe(map(userSnapshot => {

      return userSnapshot

    })).subscribe((userSnapshot) => {
      const contact: Contact = new Contact(
        {
          uid: userSnapshot.data()['uid'],
          firstName: userSnapshot.data()['firstName'],
          lastName: userSnapshot.data()['lastName'],
          initials: userSnapshot.data()['initials'],
          email: userSnapshot.data()['email'],
          displayName: userSnapshot.data()['displayName'],
        }
      )
      console.log(contact);

      this.contactData$ = of(contact);
    })
  }
```

```
latest Error Message:

core.mjs:8400 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.
    at createInvalidObservableTypeError (throwUnobservableError.js:2:12)
    at innerFrom (innerFrom.js:37:43)
    at doInnerSub (mergeInternals.js:19:18)
    at outerNext (mergeInternals.js:14:57)
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at subscribe.innerSubscriber (switchMap.js:14:144)
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at Observable._subscribe (innerFrom.js:51:24)
```

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If so acknowledge it if not then we can solve it further.

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you are trying to subscribe to an undefined Observable. As per rxjs [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map#signature-map-project-function-thisarg-any-observable) operator takes a function as an argument, and that function is used to transform each item in the Observable into a new item.

```
map(project: Function, thisArg: any): Observable // your function should return an Observable
```

In your case, you are passing a function that simply returns the `userSnapshot` object which is not an Observable, so it cannot be subscribed to.

Instead you can return Stream of `userSnapshot` using rxjs **[of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of)** which will return an Observable that emits that item once.

Updated Code :

```
getContactData(userId) {
    const contactUserDoc = this.usersCollection.doc(userId);
    contactUserDoc.get().pipe(
        map(userSnapshot => {
            return of(userSnapshot); //  notice
        }),
    ).subscribe((userSnapshot) => {
        const contact: Contact = new Contact({
            uid: userSnapshot.data()['uid'],
            firstName: userSnapshot.data()['firstName'],
            lastName: userSnapshot.data()['lastName'],
            initials: userSnapshot.data()['initials'],
            email: userSnapshot.data()['email'],
            displayName: userSnapshot.data()['displayName'],
        })
        console.log(contact);
        this.contactData$ = of(contact);
    })
}
```

This will just solve your error but for your goal you should be doing as follows :

```
getFbContactData() {
    this.contacts = [];
    this.activeUsersDoc.get().pipe(
        switchMap(userSnapshot => {
            const contactIds = userSnapshot.data()['contacts'];
            return from(contactIds).pipe(
                concatMap((contactId) => {
                    return this.getContactData(contactId);
                }),
            );
        }),
    ).subscribe((contact) => {
        this.contacts.push(contact);
    });
}

getContactData(contactId) {
    const contactUserDoc = this.usersCollection.doc(contactId);
    return contactUserDoc.get().pipe(
        map(userSnapshot => {
            const contact = new Contact({
                uid: userSnapshot.data()['uid'],
                firstName: userSnapshot.data()['firstName'],
                lastName: userSnapshot.data()['lastName'],
                initials: userSnapshot.data()['initials'],
                email: userSnapshot.data()['email'],
                displayName: userSnapshot.data()['displayName'],
            })
            return contact;
        }),
    );
}
```

Reference : **[Rxjs Map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map)**

Comment: @IngoHe Hi does my posted answer help you ? If so acknowledge it if not then we can solve further.